# How to move MVC 5 IdentityModels.cs into a separate assembly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, identity, asp.net-mvc-5

I wonder if someone ran into the issue that I am having with trying to move `ApplicationUser` into Models project (where all other models reside including the ones related to Users table).

My test MVC 5 solution consists of a web project and two class libraries: one for data access layer (DAL) and the other for Models. I references AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework in all three projects.
In my DAL class I implement Repository pattern and a UnitOfWork. UnitOfWork extends `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>`. ApplicationUser : IdentityUser is in Models class library.

In my web project UnitOfWork is instantiated using Autofac DI.
For regular controllers I defined a base class that inherits from Controller and takes IUnitOfWork as a parameter in the constructor. All controllers inherit from my custom base controller. 
I ran into a problem with `AccountController`. It has two constructors: one with no parameters that seems to instantiate `ApplicationDbContext`, the other takes UserManager as a parameter.

The parameter-less constructor gives me most of the grief. I tried many things: make `accountcontroller` inherit from my custom base controller, then try to inherit it from the Controller class. At best I succeed in making my solution compile but when I test the app and fill out user Registration form I get 'Object is not instantiated' message. When I debug I see that the second constructor in `AccountController` gets called but `UserManager` is null there.

Any ideas? I would really appreciate somebody's brainy input into this.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [SimpleSecurity Project](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/).  This project decouples ASP.NET Identity from the web application and puts [ApplicationUser into an assembly separate from the web application](https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity/Entities/ApplicationUser.cs). This project also has a version that uses SimpleMembership. For ASP.NET Identity look in the AspNetIdentity folder. The assembly for the security functions is in AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity and the reference web application is in AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity/RefApp.

Comment: Kevin, thanks for your quick response. Btw, I am big fan of your blog.

Comment: I looked at the project and I see the ApplicationUser model being moved to a separate assembly. My confusion is with AccountController.cs. It looks like the reference application in AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity.RefApp still uses WebSecurity API. I want to be able to use UserManager in my web app. Hope you have some thoughts on that.

Comment: The WebSecurity API is just a facade class I developed to encapsulate the ASP.NET Identity features. The reason I made the API mimic WebSecurity was so I could plug this into an application that previously used SimpleMembership without making any changes. For example, if you look at the implementation of WebSecurity here https://simplesecurity.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#AspNetIdentity/SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity/WebSecurity.cs and look at the ValidateUser method, it is using the UserManager.

Comment: Thank you Kevin. Your code samples helped me figure out what the problem was.

Comment: Am I wrong or this sample doesn't keep ApplicationUser on Models project ? I see ApplicationUser in one assembly but models on other.

Comment: @Bart - You are correct, ApplicationUser is moved to SimpleSecurity.AspNetIdentity project under the Entities folder, where it should be.  This is one of the entities that defines the database for EF code-first. I am not sure why the MVC scaffolding throws this under Models in the default implementation since it is not a Model used by any of the Views. I guess they did not know where else to put it. The items remaining under Models are used by Views.

Comment: Was pointing out because question is about having all the entities in the same place/assembly which makes sense to me. I managed to do it using CustomUser on the Core project and creating an ApplicationUser : CustomUser on Data. not sure if that's good design or not tho.