# ASP.NET Web Forms and Identity: Move IdentityModels.cs to another project

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to move IdentityModels.cs to another project to keep the web site apart from the Data Access Layer.

I followed this tutorial: http://blog.rebuildall.net/2013/10/22/Moving_ASP_NET_Identity_model_into_another_assembly

And also checked this question here: [How to move MVC 5 IdentityModels.cs into a separate assembly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20535570/how-to-move-mvc-5-identitymodels-cs-into-a-separate-assembly)

But I'm still confused because **IdentityModels** references another class called **ApplicationUserManager** as you can see bellow:

```
 public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public ClaimsIdentity GenerateUserIdentity(ApplicationUserManager manager)
    {
//code removed for simplicity
    }
}
```

When I went to search where was that class, I found it in the website project inside a class located in: App_Start/IdentityConfig.cs

```
//...More code in the upper section
public class SmsService : IIdentityMessageService
{
    public Task SendAsync(IdentityMessage message)
    {
        // Plug in your SMS service here to send a text message.
        return Task.FromResult(0);
    }
}

// Configure the application user manager used in this application. UserManager is defined in ASP.NET Identity and is used by the application.
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> store)
        : base(store)
    {
    }
//More code bellow this...
```

Now, this brought me here because I'm really lost in the new ASP .NET Identity framework and I been struggling with really simple things that apparently aren't so simple.

How can I move the IdentityModel to another project without messing up my web site??

Some additional data:

- Using VS 2013 Community
- Using .NET Framework 4.5.1

Comment: I have the same issue. I'm working on it, If I get an answer i'll post it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I successfully did this today after reading several posts that didn't seem to quite have all the pieces I needed. I hope this helps someone else.

My Goal: move models from existing web project into a different project. This includes domain models, business logic, and **ASP Identity models**.

[**EDIT:** Somehow I missed that the question was for Web Forms. I did this in MVC. However, I believe most would still hold true from what I'm seeing in a VS2013 web form project.]

**Step by step:**

Added new class library to solution named xyz.Models (xyz is the existing web project’s namespace) – *using something else like ModelLib is fine, you’ll just have to search/replace namespaces later whereas the former you won't.*

From the web project, move all domain models to the class library. I included the database context class (exam. XyzContext.cs), all AspNet... models, and the IdentityModels.cs. *Note: leave microsoft's default **ManageViewModels.cs** where it is for the moment.*

Next, I moved the ManageViewModels.cs into my web project’s ViewModels folder and changed it’s namespace from Models to ViewModels. The existing cshtml files in Views/Manage need to reflect this namespace change as well.

Next, ManageViewModels.cs is used by **ManageController.cs** so I added ‘using xyz.ViewModels’ to ManageController.cs.

Next, with an empty Models folder in my web project, I excluded it from the project.

Next, from the web project’s App_Start, I moved the **IdentityConfig.cs** to the models class library and changed it’s namespace to xyz.Models *(also removed its ‘using xyz.Models’ statement)*

Next, I added the class library (xyz.Models) as a reference to the web project.

Next, I installed the following NuGet Packages into the Class Library

- **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework**
- **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin**
- **Microsoft.Owin** *(I just got the latest version from NuGet, which was
  slightly newer and forced me to update the existing reference on the
  web project – easy using NuGet’s Manage Packages > Update)*

**The following may not apply to your project, but these are other things I needed in the class library based on some business logic classes:**

- A reference to ‘**System.Web.Mvc**’
- A reference to ‘**System.Web**’ – *Note: it was necessary to add a project
  reference to System.Web because I was using **HttpContextBase**,
  **HttpContext** in the class library (this was confusing at first since
  my class already had a ‘using System.Web’ statement. I won’t hash out
  why here, but just make sure you have ‘System.Web’ in your project
  references (System.Web.Mvc alone won’t do).*

While at it, as my own preference, I changed “DefaultConnection“ in my IdentityModels.cs to the database context that I am using for my others (*and deleted the reference in my web project's web.config for DefaultConnection; keeping “XyzContext”.) Note: all tables are in same db*.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext()
        : base("XyzContext", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }
}
```

At this point, compiling gave me a '**GetOwinContext**' error in one of my custom classes that I had created for centralizing some aspnet identity business logic. To resolve this I needed another NuGet package in my class library:  **Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb**.

All worked fine after that.

Comment: Don't think I didn't see your answer, I am about to check your step by step to see if it works for me. Thanks for sharing and I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It is never too late. I tested your suggestion step by step and it worked just right. You should correct a typo in the name of the package **Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owen** to **Owin**. It is a good start point to continue from, thanks! :)

Comment: I still have a question though, do you use both datacontext? The one for your business tables and the default created for identity?

Comment: @Felipe... I'm glad it helped. I was using different datacontexts for business and identity until I did the above (that's what I was referring to near the bottom when I mention: "While at it, as my own preference..."). All my tables are in the same db and although i see no compelling technical reason to consolidate, it was a personal preference.

Comment: As a WebForms user (.NET v4.5.1): I just moved IdentityModels.cs and IdentityConfig.cs to my new project and changed their namespaces to match my library. Then I compiled it and fixed the namespace references to the classes in those files and imported the required references and Nuget packages. Rinse, lather, repeat until it compiles. It takes a few minutes, but it's pretty pain free.

Comment: Great answer, very detailed.

Comment: Hi. I'm not sure about this, but I think we are not supposed to be adding `System.Web.Mvc` and `System.Web` in the class library for Data Access. I think those assemblies are to be used in the Web project. Perhaps your classes that use `HttpContextBase` and `HttpContext` should be transfered to the Web project, instead of being placed in the Data Access class library.

... But, thanks for your answer.  :)

Comment: @JboyFlaga, I think you're right. Getting the Context in the web project and passing it to the db services class is a better practice. I began to realize that myself after doing a  couple projects with .Net Core. With Core, I find it painful to do otherwise... probably for the best. In fact, this particular project has since been converted to .Net Core.